# Can't install umlet under Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, eclipse, wine

I'm trying to install umlet.
I have tried quite a lot of different configurations, but none worked.
Whether trying from the .jar itself (java -jar umlet.jar), whether using it as an eclipse plugin, or even trying wine umlet.exe, it always fails to load.
I think it might be caused by java itself, though I'm not sure.
I have tried both openJDK and the legacy java, but none worked.

`java -version` returns `openJDK 1.6`.

From Eclipse, the error returned is:

> Could not open the editor: The editor class could not be instantiated. This usually indicates a missing no-arg constructor or that the editor's class name was mistyped in plugin.xml.

From `java -jar umlet.jar`, the error is:

```
23 | ERROR | com.baselet.control.Main - "Initialization or uncaught outer Exception"
at java.awt.HeadlessException
[at ... etc...]
```

From Wine, the error is

> wine: Install Mono for Windows to run .NET 2.0 applications.

I am looking for any solution that would make that software work.

Comment: Which version of ubuntu? Have you tried oracle javac? Have you tried sudo apt-get install umlet? Have you installed mono?